# Spring rabbit starts SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor threads that don't let Tomcat shutdown

Tags: tomcat, spring-rabbit

When shutting down Tomcat it hangs.  A thread dump shows eight non-daemon threads that are still running for example:

```
"SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1" #191 prio=5 os_prio=0      tid=0x00007fb138cfa000 nid=0x1e8c waiting on condition    [0x00007fb137bfa000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
- parking to wait for  <0x00000000e03e5198> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:467)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.nextMessage(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:359)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1000)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:989)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$700(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:82)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1103)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

These threads are not started when I run the app through intellij and shutdown happens correctly when done through intellij.  They are only starting when the web app is started with the startup shell script.

How can I determine what is causing these threads to be created and why they won't shut down?

**Update: Here is the web.xml for my project.**

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1"
     metadata-complete="true">

<absolute-ordering/>

<display-name>Test Web</display-name>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath*:spring/app-context.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSessionRepositoryFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSessionRepositoryFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>corsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>corsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>etagFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.ShallowEtagHeaderFilter</filter-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>etagFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/resource/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Comment: Do you see in the dump where `0x00000000e03e5198` is being locked (you should be able to)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That implies the application context is not being shut down properly. These threads are used in the `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` to deliver messages to the listener.

How are you loading the application context? If you are doing it in your code, it is your responsibility to `close()` the context to stop the containers.

In a web container, the context should be loaded by a `DispatcherServlet`, a `ContextLoaderListener`, or a `WebApplicationInitializer` so that it is shut down properly.

Comment: I load my application completely through the web.xml file.  There are 17 similar threads for each of my consumers that are also loaded. Those are shutdown correctly.  I notice when I load my app in intellij only those 17 are started, but when I start it just through tomcat an additional 8 threads are started which also matches the number number of inbound channel adapters I have.  I will try to switch to WebApplicationInitializer to see if that works around it.

Comment: It sounds like you might be loading 2 contexts and one of them is not shutting down; edit your question with your web.xml. It's a common mistake.

Comment: The issue was the loading of multiple contexts. I had more than one file called app-context.xml on the classpath.